# How do I install Cyanogenmod on my LG L65 Using a Linux PC?

Tags: cyanogenmod, linux

<s>I don't know if my device is supported, or how I install Cyanogen mod with a Linux PC (Kubuntu 14.04)</s>

Edit1: 
One year has passed now, and im wondering if this is possible now, with the same phone (LG L65). Using Kubuntu 15.10 now.

Answer (score 2):

I just did it "using Linux". I followed [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=1b7e529f3d66c29297fb982f2117b7e4&p=61197983&postcount=8) that is an English translation from [this tutorial in Polish](http://forum.android.com.pl/topic/232755-source511-unofficial-cyanogenmod-121-dla-d280n/).

In fact, what I realized is that all commands I would use in a Linux machine I can use directly in a terminal in the rooted phone. So I used Linux to put all files in the SD card, and then used the terminal in the phone to mod it.

The steps I followed were:

- Root the phone
- Install BusyBox and a terminal emulator (not sure the BusyBox is needed, but I've installed it anyway because it was in the tutorial)
- Copied all files to the SD card (aboot.img, TWRP recovery, CM, gapps, etc)
- Used the terminal emulator in the phone to run the "dd" commands. It is annoying to type everything, and I checked the "if" and "of" paths several times before entering the command. The contents of the SD card were found in /storage/external_SD/.
- To reboot into recovery mode I used "reboot recovery". This took me to TWRP recovery.
- There I made the backup of System, Data and Boot to my SD card
- Then I wiped Dlavik Cache, System and Data
- Then I installed CM, and GApps. In my case I installed the Pico version of GApps, since the LG L65 doesn't have lots of internal memory.

A tip if you're new to modding like I am: the things you want to install should be copied to the SD card in their zip files. The first time I extracted them to the SD and then I couldn't install after wiping out the phone. Then I had to recover the system from the backup to be able to copy the compressed file to my SD card.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's no support at the moment, the L65 is not [not listed on CyanogenMod's LG supported devices section](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=%22LG%22;).

Comment: Will the windows installer warn me if it isnt supported?

Comment: Very likely, yes. Reason: Each device need it's own (different) ClockworkModRecovery (CWM) and CyanogenMod firmware build. The installer therefore needs to exactly detect the phone model and look up if there's support for it. While I haven't tested this (don't have a Windows PC) nothing else makes sense to me.

Comment: Hey @ce4 , a year has passed now, could it be possible now?